# How to filter based on something other than ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, get-mapping

I am trying to build a very small REST API with a mysql database. I am using Spring boot and Tomcat to deploy it locally. One of the services I am working on is to retrieve messages from the database. I have the ability to get ALL the messages created from the database, and I have the ability to filter based on ID but I want to be able to filter based on other parameters as well. The other parameters are called "messageCreated" and "messageSubscribed" they're both int parameters.

Here is my Controller class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/messages")
 public class MessageController {
    @Autowired
     MessageService messageService;

@GetMapping("")
public List<Message> list() {
    return messageService.listAllMessage();
}


@GetMapping(value ={"/id"})
public ResponseEntity<Message> get(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    try {
        Message message = messageService.getMessage(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Message>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Message>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}

@PostMapping("/")
public void add(@RequestBody Message message) {
    messageService.saveMessage(message);
}
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> update(@RequestBody Message message, @PathVariable Integer id) {
    try {
        Message existMessage = messageService.getMessage(id);
        message.setId(id);
        messageService.saveMessage(message);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
@DeleteMapping("/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable Integer id) {

    messageService.deleteMessage(id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Use a java stream pipeline.**
   assuming that there's a method filtering the result of your `listAllMessage()`, we say, `buildMsgsFromWanted`

```
List<Message> buildMsgsFromWanted(List<Message> allResults){
  // there should be some codes to check the validation of allResults, like ifEmpty() or something like this. then 
  List<Message> createdMsgs = allResult.stream().filter((item)->item.messageCreated()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return createdMsgs;
}
```

2. **Just query the wanted items.**
   if ur using MyBatis, in the mapper, `selectAllMessages()` should be like this:

```
List<Message> selectAllMessages(Message filter);
```

and in the mapper xml file, the sql should be like:

```
<select id="selectAllMessages" parameterType="XXX.XXX.XXX.Message" resultMap="messageMap">
  select m.fieldA, m.fieldB, m.filedC, ...., m.is_created, m.is_subscribed from message m
  <where>
    <if test="messageCreated!=null"> and m.is_created=#{messageCreated}</if>
    <if test="messageSubscribed!=null"> and m.is_subscribed=#{messageSubscribed}</if>
  </where>
</select>
```

so whether the `messageCreated` and `messageSubscribed` are null or not in the parameter `message` you pass to `selectAllMessage` decides the result, or actually, the sql executed. just call the select method like:

```
Message queryObj = new Message();
queryObj.setCreated(null);
queryObj.setSubscribed(1);
mapper.selectAllMessage(queryObj);
```

then you'll get the subscribed messages because the argument in xml file `if test="messageSubscribed!=null"` is true and `where m.is_subscribed=1` will be appended to the query sql.The downside is that you must maintain all the parameters as fields in class `Message` on which the filter may based.
It's the same in other dao frameworks, just control the 2 parameters finally passed to sql executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring data then use @Query to filter . more example find in the below url.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query